# VPN keeps disconnecting ubuntu 22.04, internt connection remains connected

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Suddenly, my VPN is disconnected. My VPN stays connected for less than a minute, then it gets disconnected. I have tried most of the solutions.

**solution 1: trying to run my OpenVPN file**

`sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn`

**Solution 2 : [Can't connect to VPN after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407774/cant-connect-to-vpn-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04)**

**Solution 3: [22.04 l2tp client not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405854/22-04-l2tp-client-not-working)**

nothing worked for me.

Comment: When running `openvpn` manually, does it log anything interesting on disconnect? Without seeing the log, the disconnect could be caused by almost anything. Before posting the log, make sure to redact any private information.

Comment: @Sheldon 22022-05-15 19:42:58 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]35.232.239.7:2294
2022-05-15 19:42:59 [35.185.181.3] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]35.232.239.7:2294
2022-05-15 19:43:01 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1: block-outside-dns (2.5.5)
2022-05-15 19:43:01 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
2022-05-15 19:43:01 net_iface_mtu_set: mtu 1500 for tun1
2022-05-15 19:43:01 net_iface_up: set tun1 up
2022-05-15 19:43:01 net_addr_ptp_v4_add: 192.168.255.38 peer 192.168.255.37 dev tun1
2022-05-15 19:43:01 Initialization Sequence Completed

Comment: it keeps on restarting the VPN process @Sheldon

Comment: In that log i can only see a connect, but no disconnect. When you run `openvpn` manually, i don't believe that the process /restarts/. It might /reconnect/, and it would be good to see the log during such a reconnect, but i believe that the process is still the same.

Comment: Also please add new information (eg. log) to your question (instead of the comments section), it's much easier to read when being properly formatted and all in one place.