# Can't connect to VPN which uses Password authentication after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 22.04, password, vpn

After upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 I am unable to connect to my work's VPN.

I've checked the settings and nothing has changed.
I have tried the following and none of them work:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1960268/comments/32

[Can't connect to VPN after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407774/cant-connect-to-vpn-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04)

https://devcoops.com/fix-vpn-connection-issue-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22.04/

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/umk1vt/cant_connect_to_vpn_after_upgrading_to_ubuntu_2204/

I do not require a certificate to connect to my VPN, my VPN uses the Password authentication type.  Every other solution that I have found so far pertains to VPN connections that use a certificate but my connection uses password authentication and to date I haven't found anything that works.

There is no the line that starts ca= in the .nmconnection file in case anyone is wondering since this VPN used the password authentication type instead of the certificate type.

Looking at the NetworkManager logs (Actual VPN name was removed):

It seems like initially the connection is successful

```
Mar  6 16:43:44 jeremy-pc NetworkManager[1698]: <info>  [1678113824.9240] vpn[0x55fdfbd1c9e0,<uuid>,"<VPN name>"]: starting sstp
Mar  6 16:43:44 jeremy-pc NetworkManager[1698]: <info>  [1678113824.9243] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="<uuid>" name="<VPN-name>" pid=5575 uid=1000 result="success"
```

I see that there was a failure when verifying the server certificate.  This was working in Ubuntu 20.04

```
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc sstpc[20294]: Verification of server certificate failed
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc pppd[20287]: Modem hangup
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc NetworkManager[20287]: Modem hangup
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc NetworkManager[20287]: Connection terminated.
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc pppd[20287]: Connection terminated.
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc nm-sstp-service[20253]: handle_set_state
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc NetworkManager[1698]: <warn>  [1678113836.3708] vpn[<some-uuid>,"<vpn name>"]: dbus: failure: connect-failed (1)
Mar  6 16:43:56 jeremy-pc pppd[20287]: Exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by performing the following 2 steps:

1. Modify the configuration file /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1960268/comments/32
2. Disable IPv6 settings for that VPN connection.
   [Disable IPv6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZOO6.png)

I noticed from the system logs that the IPv6 settings that were been sent by the VPN server were invalid so disabling IPv6 fixed the issue.  The certificate error was somewhat of a red herring. In Ubuntu 20.04 it wasn't necessary to make the above changes.