# How to enable OpenVPN's BF-CBC in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, openvpn

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 (which ships OpenVPN 2.4.7) to Ubuntu 22.04 (which ships OpenVPN 2.5.5), and in [OpenVPN 2.5.0 changelog](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/release/2.5/Changes.rst#new-features) i find

> #### Removal of BF-CBC support in default configuration:
>
> By default OpenVPN 2.5 will only accept AES-256-GCM and AES-128-GCM as
> data ciphers. OpenVPN 2.4 allows AES-256-GCM,AES-128-GCM and BF-CBC
> when no --cipher and --ncp-ciphers options are present. Accepting
> BF-CBC can be enabled by adding
>
> ```
> data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:BF-CBC
> ```
>
> and when you need to support very old peers also
>
> ```
> data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC
> ```
>
> To offer backwards compatibility with older configs an explicit
>
> ```
> cipher BF-CBC
> ```
>
> in the configuration will be automatically translated into adding
> BF-CBC to the data-ciphers option and setting data-ciphers-fallback to
> BF-CBC (as in the example commands above). We strongly recommend to
> switching away from BF-CBC to a more secure cipher.

and I can no longer connect to an OpenVPN server at work. Hence the question, how do I enable OpenVPN's `BF-CBC` in 22.04?

I did some googling, and allegedly in Fedora Linux, you enable it by adding
`providers legacy default` to `/etc/openvpn/client.conf` , but that file does not exist in Ubuntu, instead there is an (empty) directory path `/etc/openvpn/client`

Comment: How are you using OpenVPN? Is it via the Network Manager GUI? Or do you run `systemctl  start openvpn-client@<something>`? Or some other way?

Comment: @muru i run the cli ```sudo openvpn Hans.ovpn``` and the ovpn file looks like: https://termbin.com/jfdo2

Comment: Try adding `data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:BF-CBC` to the `Hans.ovpn` file.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line: `providers legacy default` in my conf.vpn file solves the issue for me.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Network Manager GUI?

Comment: You can edit the `.vpn` file you select with the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution for this post
https://askubuntu.com/a/1436542/849570

Or wait for this PR to merge
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openvpn/-/merge_requests/70

Or add this parameter
`data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC`
https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/Changes.rst