# Unable to connect OpenVPN on Ubuntu latest release

Tags: network-manager, openvpn, 22.04

I have an OpenVpn server built-in on my gateway modem. There is not much configuration make on that one except tcp/udp and home network/home network and internet.

I can connect my vpn server with android, windows and other linux clients(OpenSuse).

When I try to import the config or select files manually on ubuntu network manager, I can not connect the server.
[I tried both options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm0U5.png)
[Import config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVRYK.png)
When I go with *openvpn --config client.ovpn* on cli. I got the error below related to SSL handshake.

What I did on OpenSuse was the same. I only imported the config file and click on connect. This file contains server information ports and protocol, ca and client certs and a key. It does not require username and password.

I should probably install certs on ubuntu manually in order my ubuntu client to connect the server. Because when I imported the config file on Suse, it asked me to save the certs under */home/work/.local/share/networkmanagement/certificates* But there is no path on networkmanagent/certificates path on ubuntu. I saw certificates and the key under */home/work/.cert/nm-openvpn* . Same name with the second screen shot here.
I've done some research but could not find the way to solve it.

Regards.

```
root@mypc:/home/work/Downloads# openvpn --config client.ovpn
2022-04-30 01:40:08 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2022-04-30 01:40:08 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-128-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-128-CBC' to silence this warning.
2022-04-30 01:40:08 OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
2022-04-30 01:40:08 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
2022-04-30 01:40:08 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2022-04-30 01:40:08 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]myIP:1194
2022-04-30 01:40:08 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2022-04-30 01:40:08 UDP link local: (not bound)
2022-04-30 01:40:08 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]myIP:1194
2022-04-30 01:40:08 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]myIP:1194, sid=24e089df a65c3ece
2022-04-30 01:40:09 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=openvpn CA
2022-04-30 01:40:09 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=openvpn-server
2022-04-30 01:40:09 OpenSSL: error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error
2022-04-30 01:40:09 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
2022-04-30 01:40:09 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
2022-04-30 01:40:09 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
2022-04-30 01:40:09 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
2022-04-30 01:40:09 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
2022-04-30 01:40:14 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
```

Comment: I have gone with this one which solves the issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049798/cannot-connect-to-openvpn-after-upgrade-to-18-04/1049802#1049802